# How do we activate and use non default deactivated mutators in Pitclipse?

Tags: mutation-testing, pitest

I was using PITclipse on Eclipse to run PIT mutation tests on code. I noticed in the PIT documentation where it stated that the some of the mutators are not activated by default. Even in PITclipse these mutators do not seem to be used. I wanted to know if there was any way to activate and use the non default mutators and run the same against the code to get complete fault coverage?

URL for reference: http://pitest.org/quickstart/mutators/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences.

Under "Pitest" you have options for "Default Mutators," "Stronger Mutators," and "All Mutators."